# Print table using object of arrays AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object that looks something like this:

```js
{
  item1: [element1, element2],
  item2: [element1, element2],
  item3: [element1, element2],
  item4: [element1, element2]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to print a table with each element of each array in a new row. This issue I'm having is how to get the contents without repeating an entire `div` or `table` with `ng-repeat`.

Example:

```html
<table ng-repeat="(key, value) in accounts">
  <tr ng-repeat="element in value">
    <td>{{element}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which is giving me a new table for each `key.` I just one table with a row for each array element. Any way to do this with angular or do I need to use javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably be easier to mash your elements into one array, then repeat over that array:

```
$scope.elements = Object.keys($scope.accounts).reduce(function(arr, key) {
    return arr.concat($scope.accounts[key])
}, []);
```

And then the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in elements">
        <td>{{element}}</td>
    </tr>
```